# What's the relationship between angle $x+y$ and $w+v$ in this picture given two triangles with one side parallel formed above and below a common line?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Is

> I. $x+y> w+v$
>
> II. $x+y< w+v$
>
> III. $x+y= w+v$

> IV. cannot be determined?

Why is $x$ equal to $v$?

My idea was that the x+y is not necessarily w+v, because if you move the two triangles closer so the third vertex of the triangle with vertices A and B shares a vertex with the triangle with vertices C and D, the path from B to C is not necessarily a straight line.

[image]

Comment: <x = <v holds from the corresponding angles theorem because AB is parallel to CD (<y also equals <w because the side opposite x is parallel to the side opposite v). Thus, x + y = w + v.

Comment: [1] What is $D$ in Circle ? [2] What are the red lines ? [3] When only 2 sides are Parallel , we can not Determine what $x+y$ & $w+v$ are. When the other 2 sides are Parallel too , then $x+y=w+v$.

Comment: Here , $x=v$ with given Parallel lines $AB$ & $CD$. When we have 2 more Parallel lines , then we have $y=w$ , Otherwise , that is not true. According to OP [ & the Image } we have no more Parallel lines , hence we can not make $y=w$ , @MathMan

Comment: The second half of your comment is incorrect. In this case, we are given no more information about more parallel lines, so we cannot assume that there are more of them other than $AB \parallel CD$. Therefore,  $y^\circ=w^\circ$ is false. In this case, all that can be confirmed is that $x^\circ=v^\circ$, the rest cannot be determined from the given information @MathMan

Answer (score 0):

If the first two inequalities are true, then the third equality automatically  holds because $x+y-v-w$ cannot be positive and negative at the same time, needs to vanish.

You have not stated whether length and curvature can change.

If I understood correctly, because the angle sum is constant each term representing angle need not be equal to the corresponding angle and there are many other possibilities... like we can  assume length of a straight line AB changing and moving to position ab, as also CD moving to position cd... they can rotate arbitrarily.

[image]

Comment: Not seeing the answer.